# Visualforce <apex:map> create <apex:mapmarker> on click

Tags: apex, visualforce, google-map

I want to be able to capture the location when the user clicks on the  window.

I just need to store the coordinates, then I can display a map marker.

VisualForce Map Code:

```
<apex:map height="500px" width="100%" mapType="roadmap" center="London" />
```

From what I have researched so far, is I would need to use JavaScript to interact with the Map itself, then pass the coordinates to the controller.

Comment: what kind of window ? coordinate of current user location ?

Comment: So I have a <apex:map> that is centred to the local city, I want the user to be able to click a point on the <apex:map> and then I want the coordinates of where they have clicked.

Comment: I think, we can't do this using `apex:map` tag. Please go for google map api js.
Only showing of map, marker/pins is done through apex:map tag.

Comment: Is it possible to interact with the apex:map? For example add an event listener?

Comment: No. We can't add event listener to apex:map tag. It just render the map with markers.

Comment: You could create a `GeoCode` wrapper and than have a property that stores a `List<GeoCode>`. Iterate that property and display each wrapper instance as an `<apex:mapMarker>`. Add to that property on your click event and then `rerender` the `<apex:map>`.